# Can i have 2 windows server 2012R2 essentials on same network ? one acting as a pdc and the other one as a bdc

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012-r2

I'm about to install a windows server 2012R2 essentials as our main server. I'm worried that if it crashes later in time that I will not have another server being able to authenticate users on the domain which means that users will at some point not be able to access network shares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something in my brain saying Essentials was a single-server network solution, but apparently R2 fixed that: "Previously, Windows Server 2012 Essentials could be installed as the only domain controller of a small office network. Now ...you can have more than one server running Essentials in your domain."

As for creating a BDC later on, it looks like a second Essentials server with the DC role is referred to as a Replica vs. BDC. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408637.aspx

Actually finding out the functional difference between a replica and a BDC? That appears to take more research than finding out how to actually do it. Go figure.